# How to apply an operator sequentially to all items in a list?

Tags: python

I have an arbitrarily sized list:

```
l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, ...]
```

I want to apply the *pipe* operator to all items in the list, sequentially, like this:

```
1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 # = 7
```

I know there is a function in the stdlib that does this, and that this question is probably a duplicate, but I don't recall the function and can't find answer pointing me to it.

Comment: Lord Elrond, one does not simply apply an operator sequentially to all items in a list

Comment: What are your actual items? What type?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [`functools.reduce`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.reduce) in conjunction with [`operator.or_`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.or_).

```py
from functools import reduce
import operator
l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
res = reduce(operator.or_, l)
print(res)
```